# Passing System.Data.Linq.Table<T> into Generic Function

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to make a generic function that takes in a `System.Data.Linq.Table<T>`.

### Generic Function

```
 public int Get<T>(MyDataContext db, System.Data.Linq.Table<T> table, string PropertyValue) where T: IMatchable
 {
     T prop = table.FirstOrDefault<T>(p => p.Name.ToLower() == PropertyValue.ToLower());  
     if (prop != null)
     {
        return prop.ID;
     }
 }
```

### Interface so that I can access ID Property

```
public interface IMatchable
{
    int ID { get; set; }
}
```

### My Error

> The type 'T' must be a reference type
>   in order to use it as parameter
>   'TEntity' in the generic type or
>   method
>   'System.Data.Linq.Table'

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try specifying `where T: class, IMatchable`

Since the [`System.Data.Linq.Table`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358844.aspx) has a constraint `where TEntity : class` You need to make sure that `T` is also a reference type.